How to show that the red side wins the battle in Deitchman's model of guerrilla warfare?
I'm trying to solve the following homework question
A blue force is ambushed by a red force which benefits from cover & concealment. Red can thus aim its fire, but blue has to fire 'into the brown', with an effectiveness proportional not only to its own numbers but also to a density multiplier $R/N$, where $N$ is some fixed parameter larger than $R_{0}$. Thus,
$$
\frac{dR}{dt}=-bB\frac{R}{N} \text{;   } \frac{dB}{dt}=-rR
$$
(a) Divide one equation by the other, separate variables and integrate to find a function of $R$ and $B$ which is constant throughout the battle.
(b) Suppose that the two forces are equal, $R_{0}=B_{0}$. Blue's shooting, in a symmetric fight, would be three times as accurate as red's, $b=3r$, but red's cover imposes a two-fold penalty on blue's accuracy, $N=2R_{0}$. Show that red wins the battle.
I have done part (a) in the following way;
$$
\frac{\frac{dR}{dt}}{\frac{dB}{dt}}=\frac{-bB\frac{R}{N}}{-rR} \implies \frac{dR}{dB}=\frac{bB}{rN} \implies rN \int dR = b \int B dB \implies rNR = \frac{1}{2} bB^2 + C \implies C=rNR-\frac{1}{2}bB^2
$$
with the final expression being constant.
For part (b), I have tried substituting these expressions into the original two differential equations in the hopes that they would make something cancel out and make the equations straightforward to solve, but to no avail. One of my classmates says that if the constant value obtained in part (a) is positive, then red wins the battle but I am failing to see the link between the sign of the constant and who wins the battle. Can anyone help me?
